# osx lion python 3 pygame

Tags: python-3.x, osx-lion, pygame

apparently this is possible however I am unsure how to do it.
the closest i have came to installing pygame for python3 is http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x
following this tutorial does install python3 in the terminal. however when i call (from the tutorial, near the end) `/usr/local/share/python3/pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame` i get errors. i assume that is because the tutorial is aimed at snow leopard? if you happen to have an alternative method, please  share.

edit: didnt want to post this before because its kind of long, if fact its so long that i cut out the middle, but i figure the clues will either be at the beginning or the end...! this is what i get when i run `/usr/local/share/python3/pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame` everything else seems to run as i would imagine it to.

```
$ /usr/local/share/python3/easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.1
Processing pip-1.1-py3.2.egg
pip 1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/share/python3
Installing pip-3.2 script to /usr/local/share/python3

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
Jenss-MacBook-Pro:documents jensdonlin$ /usr/local/share/python3/pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
warning: bitbucket.org certificate with fingerprint 24:9c:45:8b:9c:aa:ba:55:4e:01:6d:58:ff:e4:28:7d:2a:14:ae:3b not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
Downloading/unpacking hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
  Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to /var/folders/v2/wmhjfmyj1fs9kwyf35mdvf600000gn/T/pip-j_nu8r-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
    Using Darwin configuration...

    /bin/sh: smpeg-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: smpeg-config: command not found
    /bin/sh: smpeg-config: command not found
    WARNING: "smpeg-config" failed!
    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 1.2.15
    Framework SDL found
    FONT    : found
    Framework SDL_ttf found
    IMAGE   : found
    Framework SDL_image found
    MIXER   : found
    Framework SDL_mixer found
    SMPEG   : not found
    Framework smpeg not found
    Framework CoreMIDI found
    Framework QuickTime found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : not found
    SCRAP   : not found
    PORTMIDI: found
    FREETYPE: found 2.4.7
    AVFORMAT: not found
    SWSCALE : not found

    If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
    the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


    Continuing With "setup.py"
    Skipping module _numericsurfarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, May 18 2012, 21:24:12)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] build.
    Skipping module _numericsndarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, May 18 2012, 21:24:12)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] build.

    no previously-included directories found matching '*/CVS'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/CVS'
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame
    Skipping module _numericsurfarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, May 18 2012, 21:24:12)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] build.
    Skipping module _numericsndarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, May 18 2012, 21:24:12)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] build.
    building 'pygame.font' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/font.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/font.o
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/font.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_ttf -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/pygame/font.so -Wl,-framework,Cocoa
    building 'pygame.mixer' extension
```

...dot dot dot...

```
building 'pygame.image' extension

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/image.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/image.o

/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/image.o -L/usr/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/pygame/image.so -Wl,-framework,Cocoa

building 'pygame.overlay' extension

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/overlay.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/overlay.o

/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/overlay.o -L/usr/local/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/pygame/overlay.so -Wl,-framework,Cocoa

building 'pygame.transform' extension

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_NO_MMX_FOR_X86_64 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/transform.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/transform.o

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_NO_MMX_FOR_X86_64 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/rotozoom.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/rotozoom.o

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_NO_MMX_FOR_X86_64 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/scale2x.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/scale2x.o

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_NO_MMX_FOR_X86_64 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/scale_mmx.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-3.2/src/scale_mmx.o

In file included from src/scale_mmx.c:33:

src/scale_mmx64.c:424:27: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'movsxl'

        asm __volatile__( " /* MMX code for inner loop of X bilinear filter */ "

                          ^

<inline asm>:1:191: note: instantiated into assembly here

         /* MMX code for inner loop of X bilinear filter */  movl             -44(%rbp),      %ecx;            pxor          %mm0,      %mm0;           1:                                           movsxl         (%rdi),      %rax;            add              $4,         %rdi;            movq           (%r10),      %mm1;            add              $8,         %r10;            movq           (%rbx),      %mm2;            add              $8,         %rbx;            movd   (%r15,%rax,4),      %mm4;            movd  4(%r15,%rax,4),      %mm5;            punpcklbw     %mm0,      %mm4;            punpcklbw     %mm0,      %mm5;            pmullw        %mm1,      %mm4;            pmullw        %mm2,      %mm5;            paddw         %mm4,      %mm5;            psrlw            $8,      %mm5;            packuswb      %mm0,      %mm5;            movd          %mm5,       (%r9);            add              $4,         %r9;            decl          %ecx;                        jne              1b;                        emms;

                                                                                                                                                                                                     ^~~~~~

In file included from src/scale_mmx.c:33:

src/scale_mmx64.c:499:27: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'movsxl'

        asm __volatile__( " /* MMX code for inner loop of X bilinear filter */ "

                          ^

<inline asm>:1:191: note: instantiated into assembly here

         /* MMX code for inner loop of X bilinear filter */  movl             -44(%rbp),      %ecx;            pxor          %mm0,      %mm0;           1:                                           movsxl         (%rdi),      %rax;            add              $4,         %rdi;            movq           (%r10),      %mm1;            add              $8,         %r10;            movq           (%rbx),      %mm2;            add              $8,         %rbx;            movd   (%r15,%rax,4),      %mm4;            movd  4(%r15,%rax,4),      %mm5;            punpcklbw     %mm0,      %mm4;            punpcklbw     %mm0,      %mm5;            pmullw        %mm1,      %mm4;            pmullw        %mm2,      %mm5;            paddw         %mm4,      %mm5;            psrlw            $8,      %mm5;            packuswb      %mm0,      %mm5;            movd          %mm5,       (%r9);            add              $4,         %r9;            decl          %ecx;                        jne              1b;                        emms;

                                                                                                                                                                                                     ^~~~~~

2 errors generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/bin/python3.2 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/v2/wmhjfmyj1fs9kwyf35mdvf600000gn/T/pip-j_nu8r-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/v2/wmhjfmyj1fs9kwyf35mdvf600000gn/T/pip-wo729f-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/v2/wmhjfmyj1fs9kwyf35mdvf600000gn/T/pip-j_nu8r-build
Storing complete log in /Users/jensdonlin/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: General tip for asking questions: if you get errors, put the errors in the question. We don't know what went wrong without that!